# How to dynamically add items to a JList?

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I'm having trouble adding items to a `JList` called `lstContacts` whenever a button is pressed.

When I press my new contact button, a line should be added to `lstContacts` but when I press the button nothing happens.

Here is my action listener for the new contact button:

```
newContactButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Contacts contacts = new Contacts();

            contacts.createContact();
        }
    });
```

Here is my `createContact` method in the contacts class:

```
ArrayList<String> contactsList = new ArrayList<String>();
public void createContact() {
    ContactsDB database = new ContactsDB();
    System.out.println("new contact");
    contactsList.add("New Contact");
    listModel.addElement("New Contact");
}
```

And lastly here is my `createCustomUIComponent()` method:

```
private void createUIComponents() {
    // TODO: place custom component creation code here
    listModel = new DefaultListModel();
    lstContacts = new JList<String>(listModel);
}
```

Why aren't the new contacts getting added to my `JList`?

Comment: strongly suggest using [GlazedLists](http://www.glazedlists.com/) -- they make automatic propagation of data from model to view very easy.

Answer (score 2):

1. Don't create an `ArrayList` of `Contacts`. All the `Contact` data should be stored in the `ListModel`.
2. So when you click on the button all you do is create a `Contact` and add the `Contact` to the `DefaultListModel`. However, your code doesn't make much sense because you're just creating an empty Contact. I would expect the `Contact` to have a name or something. So really what you want to do is have a text field were the user can enter a name and then when you click the button you create a `Contact` using the name data and then add the `Contact` to the list.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html). The `ListDemo` example show you how to dynamically add/remove an item from the `DefaultListModel`. Download the example and modify the working example to meet your specific requirements. When learning a new concept, start with working code.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
Contacts contacts = new Contacts();

contacts.createContact();
```

You are creating a new contacts object every time you click the button, but the `JList` doesn't have a reference to the `Contacts` object. I don't know how the contacts object is defined, but you should make sure that the object you are adding the contact to has reference to the `DefaultListModel`.

Another problem I see (but isn't causing the problem you posted about) is that you call `new DefaultListModel()`, but list model is a parameterized type. You probably want to call `new DefaultListModel<String>()`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to have new a default `ListView`:

```
 DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();
```

Thenm build your `JList` with this list:

```
 JList jList = new JList(listModel);
```

Anytime you want to change your list for each action you considered, call
`addElement` on your jList:

```
listModel.addElement("This is a test contact");
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).